# How to practise SN 15.14 to attain enlightenment?

Tags: papanca, fake, news

I read the following on the internet, where a person either claimed to be a Noble One or, otherwise, was exhorting with a Lion's Roar the path to stream-entry or possibly Full Enlightenment. The hairs and goose bumps stood up upon my skin as I read with awe the following Lion's Roar:

> A worldling without a knowledge of past lives would not see that as
> "incest".
>
> [SN 15.14](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.14/en/sujato)
>
> > At Sāvatthī.   “Mendicants, transmigration has no known beginning.   It’s not easy to find a sentient being who in all this long time has
> > not previously been your mother.   Why is that?   Transmigration has
> > no known beginning.   This is quite enough for you to become
> > disillusioned, dispassionate, and freed regarding all conditions.”

My question is how does believing "*It’s not easy to find a sentient being who in all this long time has not previously been your mother*" result in  becoming disillusioned, dispassionate and freed regarding all conditions?

Comment: You seem passive aggressive bro https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/8157/dhamma-dhatu.

Comment: Your wording seems to disparage the answerer of the last post. Either take this question down or fix your wording in a nice manner

Comment: This kind of behavior is toxic which makes us not use this platform.

Comment: I have deleted all my answers on your questiona thanks to your troll verbiage. With metta

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is written in an inflammatory manner and provokes worried comments by other users.

Comment: On the subject of a moderator's closing this, I guess the "inflammatory manner" might have been the preamble: "*...where a person either claimed to be a Noble One or etc.*" -- including "a person" as a subject can be contrary to the [CoC](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/conduct) whose advice is, "*Focus on the content, not the person.*"

Comment: A focus on "content" instead of "person" might be different in real life -- in real life I heard it advised to "study the teacher, and not [just] the teaching" -- but it might be good advice for 'conduct' on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you linked is truncated, as is common for repetitions of previous sections. Each section ends:

> Why is that? Transmigration has no known beginning. No first point is found of sentient beings roaming and transmigrating, shrouded by ignorance and fettered by craving. For such a long time you have undergone suffering, agony, and disaster, swelling the cemeteries. This is quite enough for you to become disillusioned, dispassionate, and freed regarding all conditions.

The point is not that making balls of mud to represent one's ancestors, or that removing mustard seeds from a three-mile-square blob once per century, is enough to achieve enlightenment; all of these discourses on causation, and these (in the Duggatasutta) concerning misery, conclude with a statement of the misery of timeless transmigration (using Bhikkhu Sujato's term for "saṁsāro"); the point is that mindfulness of all of this *may* be enough for attainment of Nibbāna.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the missing text. I suppose it makes some sense now (although it does not really because many will be inspired if all their mothers continue to be reborn thus not really die) although samsara does not mean transmigration. The Duggatasutta does not indicate any transmigration. I suggest to read SN 22.99 about the real directly knowable sanditthiko meaning of samsara. You should also be mindful Sujato is not an authority to many & mentioning Sujato's translations can reduce the credibility of answers in the eyes of some.

Comment: Since you study Pali, could you kindly explain the Pali for "your mother" in SN 15.14. Where does the "your" come from? Is not "so" a 3rd person demonstrative pronoun? Thanks

Comment: @DhammaDhatu you seem extraordinary smart why don't you answer your own questions.

Comment: @DhammaDhatu According to Bhante Dhammanando, [possessive pronouns are less frequently used in Pali](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/your-daughter-or-a-daughter-sn15-19/15419) when referring to pronouns, so the default (for example with "mātā") is to mean "your." I'm really not a Pali expert, just a student, but "Na so" in that line seems to me to mean "It's not," using the meaning "it," not "he," for "so."

Comment: Thank you Zac for explaining this. Yes, "na so" would mean "it is not".

Comment: Interesting what Dhammanando said. Based on the example from MN 130, I suppose it is true although MN 130 is contextually different to SN 15.14.

Answer (score -1):

From experience, whether I sometimes view or viewed my own wife as my "sister" isn't really your business, and youngsters sometimes think a lot of foolish things -- but certainly no-one, neither our two different families nor the laws, ever called it incest.

And I think the sutta is relevant, to the answer to your previous question. If nothing else it's a reminder that this kind of idea is in the suttas -- not only in the Jataka which you referenced. As a sutta it also helpfully includes the exhortation or conclusion (where the intent or "direction" of the Jataka may not be obvious):

> This is quite enough for you to become disillusioned, dispassionate, and freed regarding all conditions

As for your question -- "how does believing?"

It's said elsewhere that there are many "dhamma gates" as I suppose this is one.

FYI I see the sutta as having several meanings or implications.

One is to see all sentient beings as not unlike your mother -- to be treated kindly, or at least not hurt -- and to the extent that you're an adult, to avoid being a burden on them. I don't know about your own relationship with your mother (I'm pretty sure my wife's relationship with hers was not the same as mine with mine), but that i.e. "kindly" is how I see it. This manifests in Buddhist societies with people being kind or harmless even towards animals.

Another might be, are you hoping to find an object of lust out there somewhere? Someone who might be your lover or your wife? This sutta might imply there is no-one like that, instead everyone is your mother under different guises.

Another -- and I guess the main sense, a previous sutta is the "Assu Sutta: Tears [SN 15.3]" --  I suppose a lot of the audience knew very well that their birth mother was already dead, or mortal. So this is a proxy way to say, "Not just your own mother, everybody is like this."

Consequently perhaps you understand, that as a description of the "gate" itself. I'm not sure I can explain the process, of passing through the gate, e.g. how does that lead to being "released" ([vimuccati](https://suttacentral.net/define/vimuccati))? I think it says elsewhere, that the way forward begins with *sila* even if not all the perfections, but perhaps that's another gate.

If I may I would draw a parallel with a verse of the Dhammapada:

> 6.: People, other than the wise, do not realize, "We in this world must all die," (and, not realizing it, continue their quarrels). The wise realize it and thereby their quarrels cease.

Comment: Hi. It was interesting "one is to see all sentient beings as not unlike your mother". which is similar to [Bharadvaja Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.127.than.html) . This also negates the superstitious eternalistic interpretation of SN 15.14, including the suspicions of incest.

Comment: Yes, that section of the Bharadvaja Sutta reads like a parallel.